# php _POST random not working

Tags: php, forms, post

I have a strange problem.

Situation:
I have a form with the method 'post'.
Inside that form I have 1 checkbox and a submit button.
When i press the submit button an if statement will catch wether the post var is isset.

Problem:
When i press the submit button, it randomly doesn't work.
So I press it now and it works or it won't.

Here is the code I use to catch the post

```
if ( isset ( $_POST['mail_subscribe'] )  ) {
    //My code here
}
```

And here is the code from the form (I'm using smarty)

```
<form action="/my/url.html" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="mail_subscribe" class="mail_subscribe" id="{$var.graph1.ID}" {if $var.mailing == 1}checked="checked" value="0"{else}value="1"{/if} />
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="save" id="mailing_submit"/>
</form>
```

When i submit this form sometimes it works and more often it doesn't.
If you guys need more information let me know.
I'll update the question asap.

**ANSWER**

I found the answer to my problem.
Thank you @RobertMaysJr for that.

When a checkbox is not checked, and it is the only field inside the form, the form will never submit.

Now that I know that I'm changing the way I'll be doing this :)

Comment: var_dump($_POST); Put that at the top of your file that receives the POST.

Comment: won't help but thnks for the comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it needs to always be value="1" - if the checkbox is not checked then it won't be submitted at all by the browser

Comment: Thanks. I completely forgot that fact.
I will accept your answer when i can XD thnks again :)

Answer (score 1):

use this...

```
if ( isset ( $_POST['mailing_submit'] )  ) {
    //My code here
}
```

And

```
<form action="/my/url.html" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="mail_subscribe" class="mail_subscribe" id="{$var.graph1.ID}" {if $var.mailing == 1}checked="checked" value="0"{else}value="1"{/if} />
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="save" id="mailing_submit" name="mailing_submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: That wouldn't help ether because, as I now know, the form is not submited at all. But thank you for the time to answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the key `mail_subscribe` will exist in `$_POST` only  when the checkbox is checked.

So, the code will not execute all the time.

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't your form action should have .php extension file:

```
<form action="/my/url.php" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="mail_subscribe" class="mail_subscribe" id="{$var.graph1.ID}" {if $var.mailing == 1}checked="checked" value="0"{else}value="1"{/if} />
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="save" id="mailing_submit" name="mailing_submit"/>
</form>
```

And

```
if ( isset($_POST['mailing_submit'])  ) {
  //your code here
}
```

Comment: No it should not. My application is redirected with the .htacces to the index.php. From there the application will start. That way i can use urls that are like www.exemple.com/some/url/to/my/pages.html and the index.php will start the process of loading the correct page.

Answer (score 0):

instead of checking checkbox value check for submit button

```
if ( isset ( $_POST['mail_subscribe'] )  ) {
    //My code here
}
```

instead of that check

```
if ( isset ( $_POST['mailing_submit'] )  ) {
    //My code here
}
```

this will ensure form submission.
if checkbox is checked then only your code will work

Answer (score 0):

use this jquery is easier

```
$('#yourcheckbox').click(function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
       $.post('http://your form action url',{your form data },function(result){
               alert(result);
       }
  }

});
```

I have random post data method which replace all your form data into fake data during send
read here http://www.jackart4.com/article.html